# Surface SDK TagVisualizationHostAdapter internal crash

Tags: sdk, tags, pixelsense

We're working on a SUR40 application that supports tags. But sometimes we get a strange and hard to reproduce crash inside the TagVisualizationHostAdapter when moving a tag. We have a ScatterView that acts as TagVisualizationHost.

Below the stack trace. Anyone an idea?

Thx,

Maarten

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: visualization

at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.TagVisualizationHostAdapter.NotifyVisualizationMoved(TagVisualization visualization, Point center, Double orientation, UIElement relativeTo)
at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterViewTagVisualizationHostAdapter.OnContainerMoved(ScatterViewItem container, Point containerCenter, Double containerOrientation)
at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterViewTagVisualizationHostAdapter.OnContainerPositionChanged(ScatterContentControlBase item)
at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterContentControlBase.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterContentControlBase.OnManipulationDeltaPrivate(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.ScatterContentControlBase.OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.ProcessManipulationInput(InputEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationLogic.OnInertiaTick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at MaterialSource.App.Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I have fallen on this same error today.
I have tested a bit more and it seems to me the error is related to an improper contact between the tag and the surface. In my case it appears to happen if I move or remove the tag when my code is still inside the `VisualizationAdded` event handler.
If on your side you have found another reason, you might want to share it here ?
Thx
Julien